# Ubuntu installed on usb uses more than three minutes to boot

Tags: boot, live-usb, bootloader

I have installed ubuntu on an usb stick.But it takes more than three minutes to boot. I don't know what's going wrong.

Here's the details:

USB: Kingston DTMAXA 256GB 3.2Gen2
PC： MSI GP76hx i7-12800hx 32GRAM 3080ti

[image: systemd-analyze]

[usb-check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qujW1.png)

Comment: A *live* system running from *flash* media is not an installed system, and is expected to take longer to boot as it's not installed (thus more generic). Persistence does not help in this regard (*usually configuring after the live system has booted*).  Live releases past 20.10 also validate the *live* media which takes time... ie. extra processes occur that aren't performed post-installation.

Comment: This could be caused by so many things. Using a USB 2.0 port, having too many things daisy-chained on the same bus, using a slow computer ...

Comment: It's a usb 3.2gen2 port.

Comment: @Pradur, Simple speed tests for reading and writing will not always give correct results because of buffering. Often the process seems fast in the beginning but gets gradually slower, when the buffers get filled and the real speed of the USB drive hardware is limiting the speed. If you use an SSD connected via USB 3 you will notice much better speed compared to a USB pendrive or SD card.

Comment: copy that. i will try to test it on ssd @sudodus

Comment: @Pradur, By the way, is it a live system, a persistent live system or an installed system (installed like into an internal drive, but in this case installed into a USB drive)?

Comment: It's an installed system running on a usb3.2 stick@sudodus

Comment: @Pradur, OK. I'm looking forward to your result with an SSD. I think it will improve a lot, but if not there are other things to explore (to check which processes during the boot process, that need most time and try to improve the conditions for those processes).

Comment: I have full install on SSD and it is almost as fast as internal SSD with USB3. I do not now plan on buying any more flash drives as I have many. Make sure you have ESP on external drive. Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #55 or( #23 & #26)
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 or Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Comment: I tried with a fresh usb stick. The 4K performance of usb stick does matter. The boot time of my friend's fresh usb stick is much more faster than mine. It seems like long boot time only happens on mine.@sudodus

Answer (score 1):

In my case with Ubuntu live usb on a stick with 170 Mb/s read/write speed, this value is almost 2 minutes. The system become responsive much earlier, than this two minutes, no mater of background process.

It depends a lot of the USB stick speed. Slower read/write stick speed can double the time easily.

Comment: i update my usb read/write speed. It seems quite right.